# Customize the tabbar and tabbar item

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am using `UITabbarController` in my application and also I set the frame to it so that tabbar is display in center. I am so change color and image of tabbar but I want to remove the small edge its not clear how can i clear that color become white.

**Code:** `[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage : [UIImage imageNamed:@"white.png"]];`
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is, add

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

FrameWork and use

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.borderWidth = 0.50;
self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.borderColor = self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor.CGColor;
```

Comment: can i remove that border :)

Comment: Any reason why I can't modify these properties with the User Defined Runtime Attributes in a storyboard ?

Comment: @klefevre because the runtime attributes use a UIColor while CALayer's use core graphics or CGColors.
You can add a CALayer+RuntimeAttributes that converts this if you want. make a method that looks something like this:

- (void)setShadowSBColor:(UIColor *)shadowUIColor {
    self.shadowColor = shadowUIColor.CGColor;
}

then call do layer.shadowSBColor as a runtime attribute. override any other methods you'd need

Comment: @gadu I heard what you are saying and I think it could world, but I/you can modify the `borderColor` of a `UIButton` or a `UIView` through the storyboard without having to create a category.

Comment: @klefevre unfortunately whenever you're editing anything on the CALayer (layer.shadowColor, layer.borderColor, etc) you need to pass CGColor's not UIColors, and the runtime attributes use UIColors. So you actually do need to do this if you want to use a run time attribute. If you just wanted to change the entire background color or something else simple, there are default storyboard options you can use, but there's no option for partial borders or anything on storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

add clipsToBounds and set to YES.

[image: clipsToBounds]

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"transparentImage.png"]];
```

Try this with a transparent image.

**or**

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
```

These all are responsible for it. Try with second approach, as first is not working for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I already did it but there is no luck for me.

Comment: then, set `tabBar.clipsToBounds = YES;` property. @Napster

Comment: self.tabBarController.tabBar.clipsToBounds = YES; it is not working :)